# Problemas con evento click jquery al redimensionar pantalla

Tags: javascript, jquery

Resulta que tengo este problema [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si utedes notan cuando le doy mouseleave al submenú todo el nav se desproporciona. Pero cuando abro la página por primera vez trabaja bien. El problema es cuando abro primero modo movil y le doy click al boton para que el menu se despliegue y trabajo dicho evento en modo movil y luego lo redomensiono a pantalla grande es que me ocurre eso.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
  if($(window).width() <=768){

   var contador=1;

   $('.menu-bar').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (contador==1) {
     $("nav").animate({
      left: '0'
     });
     contador = 0;
    } else {
     contador = 1;
     $("nav").animate({
      left: '-100%'
     });
    }
   });
   
   // Mostramos y ocultamos submenus
   
   $('.submenu').click(function(even){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(700);
   });
  
  
 }
 

 
  
 


 
 
});
```

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,*::before,*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.clearfix::before,.clearfix::after{
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.clearfix::after{
    clear: both;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu-bar{
    display: none;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
}

header nav{
    background-color: #023859;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
}

header nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

header nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
}

header nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

header nav ul li:hover{
    background: #E6344A;
} 

header nav ul li i{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

header nav ul li:hover .hijos{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #023859;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

header nav ul .submenu li{
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    body{
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
    div.menu-bar{
        display: block;
        background-color: #E6344A;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    a.btn-menu{
        display: block;
        padding: 25px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    a.btn-menu i{
        float: right;
    }
    header nav{
        height: calc(100% - 80px);
        position: fixed;
        left: -100%;
    }
    
    header nav ul li{
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }
    
    header nav ul li:hover .hijos{
        position: relative;
        display: none;
    }
    
    header nav ul li .hijos a{
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <div class="menu-bar">
          <a href="" class="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>Menu</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>Trabajos</a></li>
              <li class="submenu">
               <a href=""><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>Proyectos <i class="fas fa-angle-down caret"></i></a>
               <ul class="hijos">
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i>Servicios</a></li>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contactos</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Intenté trabajarlo con un condicional que ejecute el evento click solo si el ancho del documento es mayor a 768 pero no funciona. Alguien tiene idea como puedo corregirlo?

Comment: ¿Cuáles serían los pasos para reproducir el problema en el [mcve] proporcionado? He intentado haciendo click en modo móvil y luego redimensionando pero no consigo replicar el error.

Answer (score 0):

debes colocar el estado siempre a `.hijos` como `position:absolute;` no solo cuando se le haga hover
**nota:**  el efecto hover se va a cancelar con el click por el slideToggle

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
  if($(window).width() <=768){

   var contador=1;

   $('.menu-bar').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (contador==1) {
     $("nav").animate({
      left: '0'
     });
     contador = 0;
    } else {
     contador = 1;
     $("nav").animate({
      left: '-100%'
     });
    }
   });
   
   // Mostramos y ocultamos submenus
   
   $('.submenu').click(function(even){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(700);
   });
  
  
 }
 

 
  
 


 
 
});
```

```css
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,*::before,*::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.clearfix::before,.clearfix::after{
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.clearfix::after{
    clear: both;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu-bar{
    display: none;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
}

header nav{
    background-color: #023859;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
}

header nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

header nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
}

header nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

header nav ul li:hover{
    background: #E6344A;
} 

header nav ul li i{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.hijos{    position: absolute;}
header nav ul li:hover .hijos{
    display: block;
    background: #023859;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

header nav ul .submenu li{
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
    body{
        padding-top: 80px;
    }
    div.menu-bar{
        display: block;
        background-color: #E6344A;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    a.btn-menu{
        display: block;
        padding: 25px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    
    a.btn-menu i{
        float: right;
    }
    header nav{
        height: calc(100% - 80px);
        position: fixed;
        left: -100%;
    }
    
    header nav ul li{
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    }
    
    header nav ul li:hover .hijos{
        position: relative;
        display: none;
    }
    
    header nav ul li .hijos a{
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
      <div class="menu-bar">
          <a href="" class="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i>Menu</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>Trabajos</a></li>
              <li class="submenu">
               <a href=""><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>Proyectos <i class="fas fa-angle-down caret"></i></a>
               <ul class="hijos">
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Submenu #3</a></li>
               </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-globe-americas"></i>Servicios</a></li>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contactos</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
  </header>
   
</body>
</html>
```